# Why is Reuben spelled with an "eu"?

Tags: etymology, orthography, names, hebrew

Reuben is most commonly spelled as such in English and in English only. The digraph "eu" as far as I know never represents /uː/ in English nor in any other language, and surely not in any Romanization of Hebrew that I know of. Why then?

Comment: Google tells me *Originating from **Hebrew**, **Reuben** is a biblical name that refers to the age-old saying “behold, a son.”* AND it says ***Ruben** is a boy's name of **Spanish** origins meaning “behold, a son”. This name stems from the Hebrew name **Reuben**, the first-born son of Jacob in the Bible.* But I don't suppose Hebrew used our current alphabet (I thought they didn't even *have* written vowels! :), so the orthography probably doesn't "directly" derive from Hebrew anyway.

Comment: In any number of French borrowings eu has this pronunciation (adieu and lieu come to mind).

Comment: Wikipedia versions also give this spelling for [Turkish: Reuben](https://tr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reuben_(Beni_%C4%B0srail)) and [Swahili: Reubeni](https://sw.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reubeni_(babu)).  My total guess is that the spelling might have come from medieval Jews in England, with the English pronunciation later changing while the spelling did not.

Comment: What the deuce! Why would you say that written ‹eu› "never" represents /u/ in English? That’s what it almost always means.

Comment: Re: _"The digraph "eu" as far as I know never represents /uː/"_: See _sleuth_, _pseudo-_, _lieutenant_, etc.

Comment: The Hebrew name has 3 syllables for an umlaut effect: Reh-OO-ven. (A dot in the V signals to pronounce it B.) So, Reuben reflects the original spelling.

Comment: @Heartspring Enrico probably meant that ‹eu› is usually /juː/, not just /uː/. But it is true that some dialects have [yod-dropping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_consonant_clusters#Yod-dropping).

Comment: @YosefBaskin Which particular [umlaut effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umlaut_(linguistics)) do you mean here? This doesn't seem like i-mutation to me. Are you referring to syllabic hiatus?

Comment: @tchrist The E and U do not form a diphthong here, but work separately. I was pointing out that the original did the same thing.

Comment: @tchrist: perhaps "umlaut" being used to mean "diaeresis"?

Comment: @YosefBaskin technicallay Reh-oo-VEN. Stress is on the last syllable.

Comment: What makes you think there is any consistency in English spelling?

Answer (score 27):

The Hebrew name ראובן is apparently three syllables. The Wikipedia article [Reuben (son of Jacob)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reuben_(son_of_Jacob)) offers the following romanizations: "Standard Rəʾūven, Tiberian Rŭʾūḇēn". With vowel markings, it is רְאוּבֵן: the vowel on the first letter (ר) is [shva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shva), which in Modern Hebrew is pronounced as /e/ (when it is pronounced), followed by the consonant א (a glottal stop /ʔ/), and then the vowel וּ (U).

The "e" in the spelling "Reuben" represents the Hebrew shva, while the "u" represents the Hebrew /u/ sound. But because English speakers are used to reading "eu" as a digraph, the name is currently pronounced in only two syllables in English.

Comment: One thing I wondered after writing my own answer is whether we perceived the [eu] in Reuben as a digraph as a result of the spelling change. Even though the Geneva Bible changed  the spelling to *Reuben* for accuracy, most people (lay or ministry) likely continued to say /u/ due to prior familiarity with the name. So if the spelling changed, but the English pronunciation stayed consistent, the prior pronunciation may have induced people to perceive [eu] as a digraph, rather than [eu] natively being read as a digraph before *Reuben*.

Comment: See also, "Michael"

Comment: In Hebrew, you would say it like this: Re-u-ven

Comment: @The other other Alan: The traditional introductory comma is often dropped before quotes nowadays; I'd say it would be seen as a throwback in such examples. But a valid comparison; Raphaël usually (!) drops the diesis now but retains the three syllables.

Answer (score 22):

The *Geneva Bible* most likely added the *Reuben* spelling to English.

### Middle English

In Middle English, the name was indeed rendered as *Ruben*. I can find mentions in Middle English of that name but not Reuben in the [Middle English Compendium](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/quotations?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search_field=quote_everything&q=Ruben), e.g.,

> Generides ther mette att a venture The kyng **Ruben**. [Generides there met by chance the king, Ruben.] (from *[Generydes](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/bibliography/BIB1343)*)

> **Ruben**, þat o broþer, þenne he is igo. [Ruben, that one brother, then he is gone.] (from *[Iacob and Iosep](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/bibliography/BIB1920)*)

This corresponds to the spelling of the name *Ruben* in a prominent Middle English version of the Bible, the [Wycliffe Bible](https://www.studylight.org/study-desk.html?q1=Ruben&OLWordSearchRange=beg&q2=&ss=0&t1=eng_wyc&t2=eng_kjv&t3=eng_nas&ns=0&ot=bhs&nt=na26&b=chapter&d=3), as well as the Latin *Vulgate* (see [Genesis 29:32](https://vulgate.org/ot/genesis_29.htm)). *Reuben*, again, is absent from the edition.

### Early Modern English and the Geneva Bible

It's in Early Modern English that the spelling *Reuben* begins to emerge. While Early English Books Online, a vast corpus of printed texts before 1700, has [2109 matches in 650 records for *Ruben*](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/t/text/text-idx?ALLSELECTED=1&xc=1&g=eebogroup&type=simple&rgn=full%20text&q1=Ruben&cite1=&cite1restrict=author&cite2=&cite2restrict=author&singlegenre=All&Submit=Search&c=eebo&c=eebo2), it has [3851 matches in 1181 records for *Reuben*](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/t/text/text-idx?ALLSELECTED=1&xc=1&g=eebogroup&type=simple&rgn=full%20text&q1=Reuben&cite1=&cite1restrict=author&cite2=&cite2restrict=author&singlegenre=All&Submit=Search&c=eebo&c=eebo2). What changes? One clue is in the first date of the result.

- *Ruben*, as expected, occurs in some of the earliest printed materials: the *Prolicionycion* [sic] from 1482, the *Legenda aurea sanctorum* from 1483, and so on.
- *Reuben* first appears in early modern translations of the Bible from the 16th century: the *Geneva Bible* (orig. published completely in 1560; [EEBO entry from 1562](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo?c=eebo;c=eebo2;didno=A10675.0001.001;g=eebogroup;rgn=full%20text;singlegenre=All;size=25;sort=datea;start=1;subview=detail;type=simple;view=reslist;xc=1;q1=Reuben)).

Here's a sample from *Geneva*, Genesis 29:32 (link to [NIV for comparison](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2029%3A32&version=NIV)):

> And Leáh conceiued and bare a sonne, and she called his name **Reubén**: for she said, Be∣cause thel Lord hathe loked vpon my tri∣bulacion, now therefore mine housband wilm loue me.

The Geneva Bible is notable for a few reasons. It was a key Bible for 16th century English Protestantism. It was the first mass-produced, printed Bible made widely available to the general public. It was the first English version to be translated from the original Hebrew, Aramaic, and Greek ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geneva_Bible)). All of these make it potent for influencing later usage. Also,  if that wasn't enough, it influenced the editorial choices of the *King James Bible*, including its spelling of *Reuben* based off of *רְאוּבֵן* (roughly *Re'uven* according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reuben)) rather than the Latin *Ruben* from the Vulgate:

> And Leah conceiued and bare a sonne, and shee called his name **Reuben**: for she said, Surely, the LORD hath looked vpon my affliction; now therefore my husband will loue me. ([King James Bible Online](https://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/1611_Genesis-29-32/), 1611 version)

So in this case, spelling closer to Hebrew was one way to differentiate the newer Protestant Bibles (*Geneva*, *KJV*) from the older ones. Nonetheless, *Ruben* didn't go away; *EEBO* results continue to the latest date in the corpus, and the name is still around today. Instead, both spellings stayed in English as versions of the name.

Comment: It seems the Geneva Bible used *Reuben* in the Old Testament translating from Hebrew but *Ruben* in Revelation 7:5 translating from Greek (Ῥουβήν ?)

Answer (score 0):

The more precise transliteration would be *Re'uven*.  Here the apostrophe stands for the guttural consonant "alef" (which has no equivalent in English).  These are routinely ignored in English versions of Biblical names, resulting in Reuven or Reuben ("v" and "b" are closely related in Hebrew; it's essentially the same letter).  Presumably this was eventually contracted to "Ruben" because the first "e" in "Reuben" does not affect the (English) pronunciation of the name.